# Send stderr to stdout for purposes of grep

Tags: grep, pipe, stdout, stderr

This won't work, because all the stdio will go to stderr:

```
webpack -w --ignore=*.js | grep ignore
```

so I try this:

```
webpack -w --ignore=*.js > grep ignore 2>&1
```

but that will write a file called "grep" to the filesystem lol

how I can I send stderr to stdout so that I can `grep` it in this scenario?

Comment: I am on bash 3.2, if I were on bash 4, I think this would work:  `webpack -w --ignore=*.js &| grep ignore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard *stdout* and match the word "ignore" only in *stderr* you can do this:

```
webpack -w --ignore=*.js 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep ignore
```

This clones *stdout* to *stderr* and then redirects *stdout* to `/dev/null`, leaving  *stderr* to write through the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I think it's just as simple as this:

```
webpack -w --ignore=*.js 2>&1 | grep "ignore"
```